# Model/View : Is it necessary to check the model index supplied is valid?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

In this example , Is it necessary to check the model index supplied is valid and the row number is within the range of items in the string list ?
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#model-headers-and-data

Comment: In this example invalid index can return negative row :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Of course if you are sure that all containers you are using inside model can handle negative indexes and indexes out of bounds you can skip certain checks, but I think it's a bad design practice. Every time you change model containers structure you have to rethink again which checks you should add/remove and if you are using Qt containers like QList etc in debug Qt will fire assertion for accessing containers elements out of bounds..